Issue with collection.load() in Milvus 2.3.7
I am currently using Milvus 2.3.7. I encountered an issue that, when I call collection.load(), it keeps running indefinitely. However, when I cancel the command, I receive the following message:
File "/home/ims/.pyenv/versions/ims_id/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py", line 1074, in wait_for_loading_collection
time.sleep(Config.WaitTimeDurationWhenLoad)
KeyboardInterrupt

How can I possibly fix this? Thank you!

When you invoke collection.load(), it repeatedly calls get_loading_progress() every second to monitor the collection's loading state. If collection.load() seems to be taking an unusually long time, there are two potential causes:

The collection may be very large, requiring extensive data retrieval from S3/MinIO. This process can be delayed by poor disk read performance or limited bandwidth between Milvus and the remote S3 storage.

There might be an issue with the Milvus server itself. To diagnose this, you should obtain and review the full server logs.


